# PowerBI connecting to Oracle client gives error

Tags: oracle, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I installed Oracle client, yet I get error when I attempt to get Oracle data into PowerBI

Please assist

Error

`Details: "Oracle: ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA"`

[image]

Here is `tnsnames.ora`

```
DLPOracle =
   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SERVER_NAME)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = service_name) 
    )
  )
```

It is in directory: `E:\app\client\adm.user\product\12.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin`

PATH contains

`E:\app\client\adm.user\product\12.2.0\client_1`
`E:\app\client\adm.user\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin`

Following service are running

[image]

@Littlefoot here is connection screen

[image]

Then I am asked how to login

[image]

And I select "Database"

[image]

Comment: How does the "connection" screen look like? Could you post that screenshot, please?

Comment: I don't know PowerBI. But, if you are pulling data from Oracle, you have to connect to the database somehow. That's what I asked: how do you do that?

Comment: @Littlefoot PowerBI gets data from pop-up (added to question). Then we are prompted to enter username and password.

Comment: Aha. So, into the "server name" field you put the database server name (or its IP address?). Then, when prompted to enter username and password, is there any other field you could enter? If not, did you try to put - for username - something like `marium@service_name`?

Comment: @Littlefoot Only username and password

Comment: @Littlefoot see updated question towards the end

Comment: I see ... huh, but - you can have access to *many* (Oracle) databases. How does PowerBI know which database you are connecting to, if you're only asked to enter username and password? By the way, you didn't say whether you tried to enter username as `marium@servicee_name`.

Comment: @Littlefoot I tried `marium` .... I will try `marium@service_name` and let you know

Comment: @Littlefoot The connection string to our database is `mary/password@service_name as marium` I tried `marium@service_name` and `mary@service_name`. Error persists :-( ----- and I whited out the Database name, but it is on the pop-up

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have any other ideas. Hopefully, someone who knows PowerBI will be able to assist. Good luck!

Comment: Normally you should be able to put "DLPOracle" in the server name field, but maybe it's not finding your TNSnames file. I've seen people say you can also put a whole connect string in the server name field, but I haven't tried it. e.g. `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_name)(PORT=port_num))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))`

Comment: @kfinity Your answer worked. I put `DLPOracle` as server name. Then I entered `marium` and `password` for credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `DLPOracle` as server name.

Enter `marium` and `password` for credentials

Thanks to @kfinity